# How to Save Dataframe as Text File using User Defined File Name in Spark Java

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, filesystems, hdfs

I am trying to save a dataframe to a specific location.

```
successDF.toJavaRDD().saveAsTextFile(successFilePath);
```

Here, successFilePath is: /hdfs/tmp/20200102/04.dat

I need to save the data with filename as 04.dat, where 20200102 and 04 are coming as arguments

But the process creates multiple files as below:

```
Folder: /hdfs/tmp/20200102/04.dat
Files:
._SUCCESS.crc
.part-00000.crc
_SUCCESS
part-00000
```

My requirement is, the output file should be created in `/hdfs/tmp/20200102` and there should be only 1 file under the folder with file name as: 04.dat

N.B. I am using Spark Java

Please suggest

Comment: if you can run job with only one reducer "SPARK" you will get it

Comment: It's not clear why you need 1 file. That's not how Hadoop should be used. If you need one file, you would download it using getmerge CLI

Comment: The file will have only one line. It is like a touch file which has one line data

Comment: Then you don't need an RDD for that. Just use HDFS API to create a file.

Comment: @Vladislav, could you please specify which HDFS API you are referring to. Just FYI, this is just a part of a bigger spark job, where i need to generate a touch file in hdfs with one line data

Comment: I've posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can create file on HDFS without using Spark:

Using [HDFS API](https://knpcode.com/hadoop/hdfs/java-program-to-write-a-file-in-hdfs/)

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

public class HDFSFileWrite {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    try {
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        // Hadoop DFS Path - Input & Output file
        Path inFile = new Path(args[0]);
        Path outFile = new Path(args[1]);
        // Verification
        if (!fs.exists(inFile)) {
            System.out.println("Input file not found");
            throw new IOException("Input file not found");
        }
        if (fs.exists(outFile)) {
            System.out.println("Output file already exists");
            throw new IOException("Output file already exists");
        }

        // open and read from file
        FSDataInputStream in = fs.open(inFile);
        // Create file to write
        FSDataOutputStream out = fs.create(outFile);

        byte buffer[] = new byte[256];
        try {
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
              }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error while copying file");
        } finally {
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```